# Admob child directed settings

Tags: android, admob

Google has  [specified](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner#coppa) that

```
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
 .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
 .build();
```

will make your ads child-friendly for COPPA compliance. I have specified this option in my app.

So, why am I still seeing ads for adult dating websites in my admob ad? Is this considered child friendly? Did I miss something Google?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to allow adult ads you should configure your ad banner settings in the **google admob dashboard**:

1. Open https://apps.admob.com/ and go to your app's banner settings page
2. Click the *"Allow & block ads"* tab
3. Click the *"Sensitive categories"* tab
4. Unselect all categories that you don't want there.

After this there should no longer appear adult ads in your app.

Comment: should I change my code by addidng tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true) and setIsDesignedForFamilies(true) or only change settings on AdMob site?

Comment: @RomanSoviak Do you have any reply for your above question?

Comment: @Siddharth sorry, it was many years ago, I don't remember :(

Answer (score 10):

Ironically, the Children's Online Privacy Protection Act has nothing to do with content.  It is directed toward keeping advertisers from collecting data on a child under 13.  As far as the FTC is concerned, adult dating ads are fine as long as you aren't passing any information about the user back to the advertiser.

In other words, AdMob isn't broken.  It is just fixing a different problem.